# Accelerometer shows the same exact behavior as roll, pitch and yaw extracted from gyroscope

Tags: navigation, accelerometer, gyroscope, measurement, inertial-navigation

I'm working on capturing dogs sitting from accelarometer and gyroscope.
The gyroscope data is stored as quaternion (w,x,y,z) for each time point.

I plot the accelarometer and gyroscope signal overtime to see the trends and behavior when sitting occurs.
I convert the quaternion data into auler format (rx,ry,rz) using the following python code:

```
def quat_to_euler(df):
    rot = Rotation.from_quat(df[["qx","qy","qz","qw"]])
    rot_euler = rot.as_euler('xyz', degrees=True)
    euler_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rot_euler, columns=['rx', 'ry', 'rz'])
```

and I notice that I get almost exact plots for the accelarometer and gyroscope.
I wanted to know, does this makes sense for rotation to show the same behavior as accelerometer?
[as can be seen in this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpCnL.png)

I would expect for the two plots to show distinct trends. although I can see how acceleration and rotation can relat,I belive there should be some difference between their behaviors.

Comment: Just curious: From a practical standpoint, how can an accelerometer provide YAW? Also, assuming the accelerometer was mounted on the dog's back & one of its 3 axis is perpendicular to the dogs vertebrae, then it would follow at least 2 sensors would experience an equal and significant change.  But your data shows only 1 sensor changed. That doesn't look right.